# Redirect based on REFERER from different pages of the same domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http

I'm looking for a `.htaccess` solution based on a REFERER from a specific page in the same domain:

#### Example #1

If a user clicks from the facebook homepage like:

```
https://www.facebook.com/
```

Redirect to:

```
https://www.mywebsite.com/targetpage
```

#### Example #2

If a user clicks from another page on Facebook, like:

```
https://www.facebook.com/ads/library/?somequery....
```

Redirect to:

```
https://www.mywebsite.com/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following using mod_rewrite near the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Link from FB homepage
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https://www\.facebook\.com/$
RewriteRule !^targetpage$ /targetpage [R=302,L]

# Link from another FB page
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https://www\.facebook\.com/ads/library?somequery$
RewriteRule !^$ / [R=302,L]
```

You need to check that we are not already on the *targetpage* in order to avoid a redirect loop.

**HOWEVER,** (usual disclaimer about the HTTP Referer)... The HTTP Referer is unreliable at best. Particularly in modern browsers with the referrer-policy, since the referring website (eg. Facebook in this example) can control exactly what Referer header the browser is permitted to send.

Comment: Plus Facebook in particular uses their “link shim” script to redirect users to external sites, explicitly so that the profile or page the user was on when they clicked the link does _not_ get leaked to the outside. https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-security/link-shim-protecting-the-people-who-use-facebook-from-malicious-urls/10150492832835766/ So I am pretty sure, what OP wants here is not really possible.